# Probability of losing one of six wagers with known failure rates.

Tags: probability

I make six wagers on sporting events but I must win all six wagers to succeed (a parlay).  I have a high probability of succeeding on any individual wager.  In fact, the chance of losing the individual wagers is as follows:

Wager 1:  2.7% chance of losing (about 1 in 37)
Wager 2:  2.7% chance of losing (about 1 in 37)
Wager 3:  2.7% chance of losing (about 1 in 37)
Wager 4:  3.1% chance of losing (about 1 in 32)
Wager 5:  4.5% chance of losing (about 1 in 22)
Wager 6:  4.5% chance of losing (about 1 in 22)

The chance of losing any individual wager is not affected by the outcome of any other wager.

What is the probability I will lose at least one of the 6 wagers, thereby losing altogether?

What is the formula to determine this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate directly the probability of winning all $6$ bets. The probability of winning the first bet is $1-0.027=0.973$. The probabilities of winning the various bets can be computed in the same way.

By independence, the probability of winning all six bets is 
$$(1-0.027)(1-0.027)(1-0.027)(1-0.031)(1-0.045)(1-0.045).$$ 
The product is about $0.814$. Thus the probability of losing at least one of the bets is about $0.186$.

Comment: Thank you, Andre!  Have a great day and fantastic weekend!

Comment: You are welcome.